# change the title of the form from separate class

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, title

hi I want to make a code in separate class that change the title of a form in c#.

```
 public static void Set_Tilte(string title)
        {
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.Text = "";
        }
```

and call the method set_title and give a string to it to change the title of form .

note : the method set_title("") is not in the same class it's in separate class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to pass `Form` as parameter, like

```
public static void Set_Tilte(Form f, string title)
{
    f.Text = title;
}
```